# Finding the count of divisors of each array item within the array

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array like: `[2,4,8,2]`. I want to find the divisor of each item in the list but the divisors can only be elements of the array.

- `2` is divisible by `[2,2]` so the asked number is 2
- `4` is divisible by `[2,4,2]` so the asked number is 3
- `8` is divisible by `[2,4,8,2]` so the asked number is 4
- `2` is divisible by `[2,2]` so the asked number is 2

I have a solution where I utilized double for-loop but I believe there needs to be a more optimal solution. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid the double loop but you can optimize them and combine them in a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

L = [2,4,8,2]
counts = Counter(L)
R = [ sum(c for d,c in counts.items() if n%d==0) for n in L ]

print(R)    
[2, 3, 4, 2]
```